# Azure load balancer does not accept HTTP DELETE request

Tags: azure, httprequest, load-balancing

When I try to execute an HTTP DELETE request I'm getting a 501 not implemented back:

Request URL: http://www..com/api/wishlist/remove?id=12345

Request Method: `DELETE`

Status Code: `501 Not Implemented`

There are three frontend (VM) servers behind a load balancer, all configured in Azure. It's working when I try it locally on one of the frontend servers.

Can somebody tell me if this is a configuration in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Load Balancer does not terminate session, it's not a proxy. If you're getting a response from the frontend IP address, you're talking to the VM instance.  In other words, the "501 Not Implemented: originates from something in the backend pool.  Load Balancer does not interact with anything above the transport layer and does not process HTTP.

My suggestion would be to check the logs on the servers in the backend pool.